# Creating shipping label not working with Fedex

Tags: admin, shipping, model, shipment, fedex

I integrated with FedEx shipping method in my website but when adding product to package while creating shipping label with this then i got below error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function hasErrors() on a non-object in /usr/www/users/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Abstract.php on line 328

Can you please help me regarding this?

It's urgent!

Answer (score 1):

That line uses a variable that should get an object from the method `_doShipmentRequest` that is extending the Abstract class. Since I'm not sure which module you are using you will have to check yourself where it fails.

It's probably a WSDL call that should be executed but is failing in some way. You will need to backtrace to figure that out

Comment: Thanks for reply. I checked with _doShipmentRequest() method in Abstract.php which line i got error. I printed $result output but this gives blank response. Thats why this give error. But how to trace this error?

Comment: The `_doShipmentRequest` should be in the shipment module you are using. In the `Abstract` class it's just there to define it. Find out which model is extending the Abstract class and see if it has the method `_doShipmentRequest`

Comment: Thanks, Actually i added shipSync module for labeling i got method but it doesn't work module at all.So i removed whole shipSync module and when i tried with simple shipping labeling but it give "An error occurred while creating shipping label." error. Can you please tell me solution for this?

Comment: This is too little information to help you. I will need some concrete errors. But since it's a third party extension I doubt I will be able to help

Comment: @SanderMangel what is the meaning of Fedex error code  1000 during creating shipment label.

Comment: My credentials correct, i have two store in single magento, store 1 display Fedex shipping cost, but store 2 not displaying shipping cost, how can i solve this issue?